# handsontable destroy and create

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I want to destroy and recreate my excel sheet i'm using Handsontable for it the object is getting destroyed and created new but the data inside the row is same for new table as well for old one

since the title is similar to [SO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054621/handsontable-destroy-and-re-create-not-working-after-upgrading-from-0-11-0-to) 
i've implemented what was the answer in previous SO question but i'm still stuck
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5zb0jph5/)

```
     <div id="example1" class="hot handsontable"></div>
    <select class="client_class">
    <option value="">Select client</option>
    <option value="DEFGH">DEFGH</option>
    </select>


    var autosaveNotification;
    var hotInstance;
    var setting1 = {
    data: [],
    colHeaders: ['InvoiceNo', 'InvoiceDate', 'Supplier'],
    columns: [{
        data: 'InvoiceNo'
    }, {
        data: 'InvoiceDate'
    }, {
        data: 'Supplier'
    }],
    rowHeaders: true,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    minRows: 5,
    manualColumnResize: true,
    manualRowResize: true,
    fixedColumnsLeft: 1,
    manualColumnMove: true,
    manualRowMove: true,
    };
     hotInstance = new Handsontable(jQuery("#example1")[0], setting1);

   jQuery('.client_class').on('change', function () {
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    console.log(hotInstance.getData());
    hotInstance.destroy();
    hotInstance = new Handsontable(jQuery("#example1")[0], setting1);
    console.log(hotInstance.getData());
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your question is that you're trying to create a new table with empty data but yours isn't doing that. The simple solution is that on the second to last line you're setting the new HOT instance to have `setting1` as the new options object, forgetting that Objects in JS can be mutated, meaning that `setting1.data` is being mutated regardless of the table.

To achieve what I think is your intended behavior, reset `setting1.data` before creating a new hot instance:

```
jQuery('.client_class').on('change', function () {
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    console.log(hotInstance.getData());
    hotInstance.destroy();
    setting1.data = []; // this is the new line
    hotInstance = new Handsontable(jQuery("#example1")[0], setting1);
    console.log(hotInstance.getData());
});
```

As you can see, this will ensure you are resetting just the `data` object. This issue occurs because HOT intentionally mutates the `data` object as you edit the table. If you wanted to, for example, save the `data` object for each of your two `client modes`, then I suggest you add logic which stores each `data` object and retrieves it right before creating the new HOT instance. Something like this:

```
setting1.data = storedDataObjects["client1"]; // if adding "client1"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but you know that my setting 1 contains all setting for the table and i want it every time when table is destroyed and created again except for data

Comment: Yes that's what it looked like. So what you wanted was a new object with the "default values". Another approach is to have a method that would create this object and return it new every time.